# Internal working of FileInputStream

Tags: java, file-io

I searched for something in Java to read the file. I found `FileInputStream` and `DataInputStream`, but I wanted to know the internal working of this stream. Can somebody explain me clearly how they work?

Comment: you can always read their implementations in the Java source code, at least until you rwach native method invocations.

Comment: What, exactly, are you wanting to know about how they work?

Answer (score 1):

How it works is different for each system (Linux, Mac, Windows, and even different versions of those.) That's what's so great about it. You don't NEED to know, you just know it is handled. You get to work with it the same on every system.

If you really want to know how it works, you'll have to look at the source to the jvm implementation for the system you're working on.

From the FileInputStream source:

```
private native void open(String name) throws FileNotFoundException;

public native int read() throws IOException;

private native int readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

This indicates it's written different for each system. But when you want to use it, you can use the same code no matter what system you're on.

Answer (score 0):

To get a definitive answer of the differences between the two (at least, from a strictly Java point of view), check out the Java API (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/api-141528.html) specification for the version of Java that you're using. In the case of JavaSE 1.6, look at [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [DataInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).

By my understanding, DataInputStream is useful for using input streams of data that is accessible within your program; whereas FileInputStream is used to access files, which are external to your program (e.g. on a filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

`FileInputStream` is a class that reads a file as a stream of bytes.

`DataInputStream` is a class that reads *another stream* and applies transformations for standard types (ie, instead of reading bytes, you can tell it to read a 4-byte `int`).

They serve two completely different purposes.

Comment: well I was trying to reading file then I searched two ways to do it given below:-                                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/pranay/Desktop/pranay.txt");
  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
           OR
                                                                                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/pranay/Desktop/pranay.txt"));